# Glass Transparency Seems Dark

Tags: rendering, glass

[image]

I rendered this glass material, however, the transparency of the glass is  darker than what I was looking for.

I tried to increase the light bounce number but it didn't work.

How can I achieve glass material that looks like this?

[image]

---

**EDIT**

The engine is in Cycles,here's my blender file, base color is pure white but it still appears grainy.

[file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19eFewOSx_rza6O-D-rScJBvfm_i-rNHF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you specify it's in Cycles or Eevee? Also please post the screenshot material settings used to create the shader.

Comment: or even better:  provide your blend file

Comment: It would help if you showed at least the nodes that you are using for the material, and specified what render engine you are using. Otherwise this becomes a guessing game of what others think you did.

Answer (score 6):

In the Principled BSDF shader, the default `Base Color` is a very light gray. To make sure the surface absorbs no light, set the Base Color to pure white.

(If you are using the Glass BSDF shader, make sure its color is white as well)

I'm assuming you have a simple 1-node shader setup. If you have something more complex, it is possible that the other materials are affecting the transparency color as well. Make sure you aren't mixing the material with a darker material in a mix node or similar.

Also check that there is no volume absorption shader set on the material. This can cause it to appear darker as well.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve "Glass material like this" I see several steps (Cycles only) :

1. As Reinis mentioned, crank the Base color to completely white
2. Add small Roughness, like 0.2-0.3
3. Add a small bevel to highlight the edges
4. Change IOR to 1.2 maybe
5. For correct shadows we'll have to wait for better caustics in Blender

The greater the IOR (more than 1) the darker the glass, which is physically correct behavior, but may not be the desired effect ;)

If that doesn't help - Youtube has great videos on Blender Architectural Glass.

Good luck with your scene!